# Как понять начертание текста внутри docx файла используя c#?

Tags: c#

Как понять начертание текста на c#?
Мне нужно определить как написан текст:

- Курсивом
- Жирным
- Подчеркнутым
- Надчёркнутым
- Перечеркнутым

Как собственно распознать начертание на c#, если текст берется из файла word?

```
StreamReader readLorem = new StreamReader(@"lorem.docx");

StreamWriter writeEncrypt = new StreamWriter(@"encrypt.docx");

StreamWriter writeDecrypt = new StreamWriter(@"decrypt.docx");

public Bacon()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Bacon_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string lorem = readLorem.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Такой код не сохраняет начертание.

Comment: Начертание это форматирование текста, оно "накладывается" на текст в специальном формате, которое реализуется той или иной программой, например Word. А `StreamWriter` записывает текст как простую последовательность символов, тут понятие начертания просто не применимо.

Comment: Так и как тогда быть?

Comment: Если вам непременно нужен *.docx, то только Word, ну или прочитать документацию по этому формату файла и написать собственные классы, которые будут записывать в этом формате.

Comment: Прочитайте про XML на базе тегов, можно написать свой текстовой формат файлов, кх-м с бледжеком и девочками :)

Comment: Вот это я попал... А более быстрого варианта нет?

Comment: А что вам мешает написать программу, которая будет запускать в фоне Word, вставлять туда в качестве документа ваш текст, форматировать его и сохранять? Можете просто воспользоваться встроенным в Word бейсиком для этого программирования внутри Word.

Comment: @Bulson не говорите чушь. Есть же библиотеки...

Comment: OpenXML SDK, родная от microsoft,  еще несколько разного качества и удобства есть в NUGET.

Comment: @kot_mapku3 вот народ уже подтянулся и указал мне на мою глупость, есть уже готовые библиотеки, бери и пользуйся!

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо, буду пробовать..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Как ранее отмечали, можно воспользоваться библиотекой OpenXML от Microsoft, которую можно  [скачать тут.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425) Итак после установки в Ваш проект нужно подключить следующие сборки:

- DocumentFormat.OpenXml
- WindowsBase

Для работы с текстом нужно подключить пространства имён:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
```

Я создал для демонстрации небольшое консольное приложение для примера, ниже расположена функция, которая разбирает форматирование текста, который содержится в файле по пути *path*. Эта функция отображает текст из документа и параметры форматирования каждого участка текста:

```
static void ReadDocx(string path)
{
    try
    {
        using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(path, false))
        {
            foreach (var p in doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>())
            {
                foreach (var r in p.Elements<Run>())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(r.InnerText);
                    Console.WriteLine("Является:");
                    if (r.RunProperties.Bold != null)
                        Console.WriteLine("Жирный");
                    if (r.RunProperties.Italic != null)
                        Console.WriteLine("Курсив");
                    if (r.RunProperties.Underline != null)
                        Console.WriteLine("Подчёркнутый");
                    if (r.RunProperties.Strike != null)
                        Console.WriteLine("Перечеркнутый");
                    if (r.RunProperties.VerticalTextAlignment != null)
                    {
                        if (r.RunProperties.VerticalTextAlignment.Val
                            == VerticalPositionValues.Subscript)
                            Console.WriteLine("Подстрочный");
                        if (r.RunProperties.VerticalTextAlignment.Val
                            == VerticalPositionValues.Superscript)
                            Console.WriteLine("Надстрочный");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы знаете я получаю `NullReferenceException`, пытаясь получить `RunProperties` для `Run`. Исследовав вопрос, скажу, что [`RunProperies` не является обязательным свойстом](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154719/net-openxml-sdk-2-runproperties-are-null). Пожалуйста, добавьте обработку этого случая.

Comment: *Просто информация для всех.* Также существуют неофициальные Nuget пакеты для Open XML SDK. [Более новый](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenXMLSDK-MOT/)  и [постарше](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/). По сути просто выложили те же библиотеки, которые вы качаете с сайта Microsoft.

Comment: Ещё замечание: можете  опустить обработку исключений для данного случая? Тут она тривиальна и просто "глотает" все исключения.